# Intuition behind the Substitutions for the Derivation of the Cubic Equation

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I have seen the derivation of the cubic equation, and it is amazing. There were 2 specific substitutions needed to solve it. From $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ the first substitution is made $y=x+a/3$, and then $y=\sqrt[3]{u}-\sqrt[3]{v}$. My question is, how did people know how to make those substitutions? I see no intuitive way whatsoever to make these substitutions. Did people just use trial and error? Thanks!

Comment: The quadratic equation is derived by using "completion of squares".  Dal Ferro's idea (which he passed to "Tartaglia"/Fontana) was to start with "completion of cubes".  You can find a discussion of the method in many places online or in texts on the "theory of equations".  The development of this method (along with its usual accreditation to Cardano: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) is historically rich and somewhat amusing...  The intent is to turn the cubic into a "quadratic" equation in terms based on $ \ x^3 \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I look at this and it is very interesting and clever. The initial substitution $y=x+a/3$ is actually used to depress the full cubic down so that the $x^2$ term vanishes.

Comment: The extension of this by Ferrari to the quartic, in order to "depress" it into a cubic equation in terms of $ \ x^2 \ $ , works similarly (but is understandbly more complicated).  Lagrange, Euler, and others then tried to push this (as well as using other ideas) to the quintic -- and we know how _that_ turned out...

Comment: Lagrange in his theory of equations describes the solutions of the quadratic, cubic, quartic in algebraically "natural" ways. Before Lagrange, the procedures, particularly for the cubic and quartic, were "tricks."

Comment: @AndréNicolas: So how did they come up with those "tricks" such as the substitutions I mentioned? Trial and error?

Comment: @AndréNicolas  I suspect that the improvements in algebraic notation and method developed by Viete (whom I have increasingly come to feel is insufficiently well-known) made it possible for later mathematicians to see more clearly ways to investigate polynomials.  Ferrari only presented his method for quartics around the time Viete was born.

Comment: Hard to know. Cardano gives a part geometrical explanation. Presumably you have discovered a trick or two yourself in solving problems.

Comment: @Ovi  I don't doubt that there was a fair bit of "stumbling around" in developing these solution methods (especially as they were encumbered with 15th- to 16th-Century algebraic notation).  Since DalFerro and Tartaglia rather jealously guarded the methods themselves, I don't think we have any records of how they reached their results (at least none I've seen referenced).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, why don't you write an answer from the comments? It would also help readability. :)